# What to do when the divergence results in z and you have to find the flux?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose I want to find the flux of $F$ through the portion of the cylinder $z^2 + y^2 = 16$ from $x = 1$ and $x = 3$ and normal points outwards of the cylinder.

$F= (z^2 + y)i+(x^2 + z)j+5z^2k$

I solved for the divergence

$div \ F$ = $10z$

How do I go about solving this triple integral in cylindrical coordinates $dxdrdθ$?
I'm not quite sure how to convert the $z$ and make it in terms of $x$ or $r$. Do I just treat the $z$ as $r$?

Comment: Please be a lot more careful about saying what *surface* you want to compute the flux across.

Comment: Ok I rephrased it @TedShifrin

Comment: Great. Thanks. Welcome to MSE. It seems like you're confused because they're doing a cylinder along the $x$-axis instead of along the $z$-axis. How do you write $y$ and $z$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$? It's precisely analogous.

Comment: @TedShifrin Would $y = sin(θ)$ and $z = cos(θ)$ ?

Comment: You need the $r$, right? Maybe $y$ should be $r\cos\theta$, but doesn't much matter.

Comment: More sophisticated comment when you're done: Think about symmetry. The region is radially symmetric about the $x$-axis, so the average value of $z$ will always be $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay yeah I see what's going on. Thank you for your help

Comment: @JasonGothright and if it was $z^2$ for example, your integral would not be zero as $f(z) = z^2$ is an even function $f(z) = f(-z) = z^2$ whereas $f(z) = z$ is odd because $f(-z) = - f(z)$. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are calculating flux including flux through the part of the planes $x = 0, x = 1$ in the cylinder.

Given $z$ is an odd function and the cylinder is symmetric with respect to $XY$ plane, your integral will be zero.

You can use cylindrical coordinates as below -

$z = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta, x$

$\displaystyle \iiint_S div F \, dV = 10 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^4 \int_1^3 \, r^2 \cos\theta \, dx \, dr \, d\theta = 0$